# An ASP.NET solution running on localhost - can we develop a C# program which can find which function got executed now on localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, localhost, clr

I need to log every function execution (on localhost) through my C# program which is running independently.

Basically can we communicate with the runtime environment through C# code for other applications?

I don't want to inject logging code in original ASP.NET solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your situation, but i got this on a class from MS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022

Maybe this can help you.